# How to get value of node instead of <node>value</node>?

Tags: xml, xpath, azure-logic-apps

I am using this code

> @xpath(xml(triggerBody()), '//*[local-name()=\"node\"]')

in my Azure Logic app to get the value of the node. But it return in this form `<node>value</node>` instead of `value`.
What is right syntax for that?

Comment: not sure about Azure Logic but try `@xpath(xml(triggerBody()), '//*[local-name()=\"node\"]/text()')`

Comment: Thanks its work for me :)